# How to check if variable is empty, and give back the same flash message with multiple variables

Tags: php, laravel

Does somebody know how i can make this shorter?

```
if (empty($location->file))
        return back()->with('danger', 'the image field is required');

    if (empty($location->culture_file))
        return back()->with('danger', 'the image field is required');

    if (empty($location->history_file))
        return back()->with('danger', 'the image field is required');

    if (empty($location->gastronomy_file))
        return back()->with('danger', 'the image field is required');
```

Comment: why not use OR ( || ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
if (empty($location->file) || empty($location->culture_file) || empty($location->history_file) || empty($location->gastronomy_file)){
        return back()->with('danger', 'the image field is required');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had already tried that myself, but I forgot the {}

Comment: Yes, I was planning, but that is only possible after a certain time XD

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to return only once, for that OR (||) expression could be used.

```
if (empty($location->file) || empty($location->culture_file) || empty($location->history_file) || empty($location->gastronomy_file))
    return back()->with('danger', 'the image field is required');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (['file','culture_file','history_file','gastronomy_file'] as $file) {
    if (empty($location->$file))
        return back()->with('danger', 'the image field ['.$file.'] is required');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!empty($location) && ($location->file || $location->culture_file || $location->history_file || $location->gastronomy_file)) {
    return back()->with('danger', 'the image field is required');
}
```